# jQuery - FullCalendar change week view by n number of days

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to set the amount of days a view goes backwards/forwards?
Or change the current week by dragging the event object to either side of the div?
The idea is to drag the events between weeks/months/days without using an outside container for the objects.

Comment: I don't think there is out of box. Shouldn't be all that challenging to code though. Just define a region on both sides of the calendar then if hovering over those sections for long enough, click() the respective button.

Comment: Maybe using the "week number". But I don't really know how just now. A good investigation may start [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekNumbers/) since it is a value available which you could compare and do some math. +1 and a follow on it ;)

Comment: Thank you look into it. Also i tried the hovering. The problem with that is how do check the calendarevent hovering and position.